# JQuery Dynamic Transition over Multiple Div Height with Decreased/Increased Contents

Tags: html, jquery

***Hi anyone,*** To my question;

The ".section,"  each may get ***dynamically added or removed content(s)*** via manual click interactions, while height:auto keeps to brought sudden changes (there’s no transition at all. The CSS max-height smooth-transition trick doesn’t worked while each of them will also have unknown height variants). Each of ".section" is unique in height (as a container which height does in depend to ones’ childs). This maybe can be done ***using some lines of jQuery.*** Is anyone know how to realise this ***dynamic height transition for each*** ".section"?

Mixing script from here and there i did learnt from this site, i’ve done this before. But it was suddenly didn’t worked anymore, don’t know where’s the wrong. Combined with the page changing (still in ***same one html***—that create another forced-adapting for the script to worked, since the page changing is using another script, jQuery base, i was giving up but now i’ve come up with idea for directly input my question right here).

```
<span class="PAGE-1" style="min-height: 100vh;width: 100vw;overflow: hidden">

<div class="section">
<p><cap>A</cap> long paragraph</p>
<p>(Another paragraph)</p>
<hr/>
<span class="panel-with-contents"><button>One from many</button></span>
</div>

<div class="section">
<span>(A lot more of mixed contents)</span>
</div>

<div class="section">(And yet another)</div>

</span>



Neither this works. This doesn’t. The one that was worked it has if( ==0){ or something but it did not even slide the height to zero, but to auto that still containing the childs. I lost it since i tried for other ones because it was not also perfect. I’m just a dumb in this.

$('s').each(function(){
var currentHeight = $(this).css('height');
$(this).css('height','auto');
var animateHeight = $(this).css('height');
$(this).css('height', currentHeight);
$(this).animate({height: animateHeight}, 600);
});
```

Comment: Just wondering - any reason you are wrapping all your `divs` and  content in  a `span` element ?

Comment: I did even unaesthetically wrap them in <page> tag to make it far shorter, rather than using span or div class="page-410". The div/span .page does covering the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Neither this works. This doesn’t. The one that was worked it has if( ==0){ or something but it did not even slide the height to zero, but to auto that still containing the childs. I lost it since i tried for other ones because it was not also perfect. I’m just a dumb in this.

```
$('s').each(function(){
var currentHeight = $(this).css('height');
$(this).css('height','auto');
var animateHeight = $(this).css('height');
$(this).css('height', currentHeight);
$(this).animate({height: animateHeight}, 600);
});
```